# codeigniter admin panel setup how to implement this

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter frame work. I have installed CodeIgniter 2.1.4 version. I set up the application and system path in my local wamp server. The front end opens fine. 
But when i try to open the admin `i.e http://siteurl/CodeIgniter_2.1.4/admin`

it shows as 404 not found. In application >> controllers >> admin.php is found (Hope this is for admin panel)

Then why it shows as 404 not found. Shall i made any setup for admin url?  Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Can you please paste content of admin.php ? Also please explain how do you call "front end" and where is that file located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need multiple things in place in order to achieve this:

1. Set the `$config['index_page']` to an empty string in `application/config/config.php`
2. You will have to rewrite the requests coming in, for example with apache you will need to have rewrite rules like this:

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1/ [L,QSA]
   ```

   You can put them into a file called `.htaccess` next to the `index.php` (your webserver need to be configured to support these kind of files for this to work)
3. You will have to have a function called `index` inside your admin.php, inside a class called `Admin`.

Comment: I have 2 controller admin, frontend. By default frontend opened. The admin controllre is not called when i use the url/admin? I have pasted the above htaccess code in application >> .htaccess. But still shows as 404.

Comment: If the `/admin` part arrives to the code it should try to find a controller with that name (except if routing config is involved) Try moving the `.htaccess` file up a directory, if it's inside the `application` then it would only be read if you hit that directory.

Comment: I placed the htaccess in a wrong folder. It is fixed now. Thanks